# Excluding certain numeric values from all columns in queries

Tags: sql

I have a table that uses numerical values -9999 and 9999 to indicate missing values.  I need to exclude all the records that feature either one of those values in my queries using the WHERE clause.  This is what I have tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM weather
WHERE (* != -9999 & * != 9999);
```

I have heard you can use `except` instead but my instructor wants us to practice using `where`.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Repeat all the columns you have in the `where`. Or add your DBMS tag for DBMS-specific solution (if possible) without manually typing all the columns

Comment: And use `AND` for and, not `&`. And use `<>` for not equals.

Comment: What is the database you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the canonical solution would be `NOT IN`:

```
where col not in (-9999, 9999)
```

Unfortunately, you would have to do this for all columns . . . although I could imagine some tricks in some databases using, say, JSON functionality.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT *
FROM   weather
WHERE  **table_column** != -9999 
AND    **table_column** != 9999;

Change table_column for the right table column, the one that holds the values.

You can also use :

...

where table_column not in (9999,-9999)

Comment: The only problem is that all the columns use those values to indicate missing values, so I'm guessing I would have to list all columns manually like astentx mentioned.